# Usage of "may" following "permits"

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I'm editing a legal document and my client was very specific about not removing words like "may," "shall," and "must." I'm having trouble rewording sentences like the following

> This bill permits a notary public may select one or more tamper-evident technologies to perform notarial acts with respect to electronic records.

Please help!

Comment: You'll have to change *permits*, which does not license finite complements and modals like *may* cannot be cast in non-finite forms. I suggest *This bill provides that a notary public ...*.

Comment: Well, the original sentence is nonsense.

Comment: Why are you editing a legal document?  Lawyers draft legal documents.  What is this bill for anyway?  It sounds like it allows notaries to decide whether they want to use tamper-evident technologies or not.  Were they not allowed to do this at all before??

Comment: "Under this biil, a notary public may ..."

Comment: Ask your client what to do when the original is ungrammatical. They probably just mean 'don't change the modal implications' (writing 'You must cross a double white line to overtake a tractor' instead of 'You may ...').

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a problem with your client, not with the English language.

Answer (score 1):

@StoneyB had a good suggestion in the comments with 'provides'. Here are two other words that could be used:

> This bill **allows that** a notary public may select...

or

> This bill **grants that** a notary public may select...